# Need the type of time complexity and its formula

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, polynomial-time

If the complexity of my problem is $O(f_n(n))$ begins at $n =4$ and increases in this sequence:

> At
>
> $n = 4$ the number of operations = $(n - 2)$,
>
> $n = 5$  the number of operations = $((n - 2) (n-2)(n-3)/2)$
>
> $n = 6$ the number of operations = $((n - 2) (n-2)(n-3) (n-3)(n-4)/4))$
>
> $n = 7$ the number of operations  = $((n-2) (n-2)(n-3) (n-3)(n-4)(n-4)(n-5)/8)$

> $n = 8$  the number of operations   = $((n-2) (n-2)(n-3) (n-3)(n-4)(n-4)(n-5)(n-5)(n-6)/16 )$ … etc.

1. How to formulate the $f_n(n)$ for all $n$?
2. What is the type of its time complexity?

Comment: Welcome to CS SE! You'll get a lot more help by providing context. Where did you find this problem? Also, what have you tried? Where did you get stuck? You'll receive a lot more help this way

Comment: [Cross-posted on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/398271/121862)

Comment: It's probably much easier to figure out if you drop the $n-X$ and write the actual numbers (and group the terms): 4: $\frac{2}{1}$, 5: $\frac{\left(3\right)\cdot\left(2\cdot3\right)}{2}$, 6: $\frac{\left(2\cdot3\cdot4\right)\cdot\left(3\cdot4\right)}{4}$, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.)**

If we look at $n=8$ then we see:
$$\frac{1}{2^4}\times\left((n-6)(n-5)(n-4)(n-3)(n-2)\right)\times \left((n-5)(n-4)(n-3)(n-2)\right)$$
$$=\frac{((n-2)!)^2}{2^5}.$$

Therefore we can formulate $f_n(n)$ as follow:

$$f_n(n)=\frac{n-(n-2)}{2^{n-4}}\times \prod_{i=3}^{n-2}i^2$$
$$=\frac{n-(n-2)}{2^{n-4}}\times \prod_{i=3}^{n-2}i\times \prod_{i=3}^{n-2}i$$
$$=\frac{2}{2^{n-4}}\times \frac{(n-2)!}{2}\times\frac{(n-2)!}{2}$$
$$=\frac{\left((n-2)!\right)^2}{2^{n-3}}.$$
So we find a closed formula for $f_n(n)$.

**2.)**

Let $T(n)$ be the time complexity of computing $f_n(n)$:
$$T(n)=\Theta\left(\frac{\left((n-2)!\right)^2}{2^{n-3}}\right).$$ That you can estimate it by [sterling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Comment: Thank you. Can we consider it as a  pesudo polynomial time?

Comment: No, obviously the complexity is super-exponential. Note that, when you use the term,  pseudo polynomial, it's means that, the complexity depend on the value, not only the size of input. But if you look at $T(n)$, you can see that the running time only depend on $n$ not any other variables.

Comment: @SAbeA [Factorials are superexponential (i.e. grow faster than exponential functions with a constant base $c^n$)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607376/which-function-grows-faster-exponential-or-factorial). So we know $\lim\frac{(n-2)!}{2^{n-3}} > 1$, thus $\frac{\left((n-2)!\right)^2}{2^{n-3}} = (n-2)!\frac{(n-2)!}{2^{n-3}}$ is also superexponential.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that:
$$
f(n) = \left( 2\prod_{i=3}^{n-2} i^2 \right) \cdot \frac{1}{2^{n-4}}
= \frac{1}{2^{n-5}} \cdot \frac{1}{2^2} \cdot\prod_{i=1}^{n-2}i^2
= \frac{1}{2^{n-3}} \cdot \left(  \prod_{i=1}^{n-2}i \right)^2
= 2^{3-n} ((n-2)!)^2.
$$

This time complexity is superexponential. Indeed, using [Stirling's approximation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/142633/need-the-type-of-time-complexity-and-its-formula):
$$
2^{3-n} ((n-2)!)^2 \sim 2^{3-n} \cdot 2\pi n \left( \frac{n-2}{e} \right)^{2(n-2)} 
= \Theta\left(\left(\frac{n}{\sqrt{2} \; e}\right)^{2(n-2)}\right). 
$$

Comment: Thank you. Can we consider it as a  pesudo polynomial time?

Comment: A pseudopolynomial running time is a time that is polynomial in the maximum value $t$*represented* by the input. You gave us no information on what the input represents. Anyway, using standard representation, an instance size of $n$ can represent integers up to $2^n$. Let's be optimistic and pick $t=2^n$. Then $f(n) = \Omega(  \frac{(\log t)^{\log t}}{\text{poly}\, t}  ) = \Omega(\frac{2^{\log t \cdot \log \log t}}{\text{poly}\, t}) = \Omega(\frac{t^{\log \log t}}{\text{poly}\, t})$, so $f(n)$ is not polynomial in $t$ either.